# How to make a compatibility compileSdkVersion?

Tags: java, android

i have a sample on git [link](https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/Accelerometer-indicator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/aleksey/accelerometerindicator/verticalseekbar/VerticalSeekBar.java) (it isn't complicated)

there is `VerticalSeekBar` class and method `setProgress()` inside

```
private synchronized void setProgress(int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (mMethodSetProgress == null) {
        try {
            Method m;
            m = this.getClass().getMethod("setProgress", int.class, boolean.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            mMethodSetProgress = m;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
        }
    }

    if (mMethodSetProgress != null) {
        try {
            mMethodSetProgress.invoke(this, progress, fromUser);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ignored) {
        }
    } else {
        super.setProgress(progress);
    }
    refreshThumb();
}
```

Issue is - if `compileSdkVersion` - 23 all is ok, but if `compileSdkVersion` - 24, IDEA says that i need change `private` to `public`, all were done. I launch my app and nothing work, because of my changes method `setProgress()` invoke itself and eventualy i get endless loop...

Help me please, how i can change `compileSdkVersion` to 24 ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to project structure->properties->compile sdk version.
select your sdk version